# How to add DateTime adapter to symfony/ux-chartjs?

Tags: symfony, chart.js, symfonyux

I am trying to setup ChartJS with Symfony UX. Since a default datetime adapter is not included with ChartJS 3+, I am getting the following error when using time unit in an axis.

> This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.

How can I add a ChartJS datetime adapter to `symfony/ux-chartjs`?

I tried importing `chartjs-adapter-moment` to my `app.js`, but this adds a second copy of ChartJS module from `node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.mjs`  to the generated bundle, and registers the adapter to this second copy.

But the symfony ux controller is using its own copy of ChartJS from `vendor/symfony/ux-chartjs/assets/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.esm.js`.

Comment: I've got the same issue, albeit when using the Luxon adaptor. Have you found a resolution?

Comment: I used moment and Luxon adapter, and it didn't work at first. But later it started working. Not exactly sure, what I changed. Not sure if it was a version conflict. I have moment `2.29.4` and  chart.js `3.4.1`. In my `app.js` I have added `import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having issues with it, despite having the same library versions it seems. If you get chance, could you update the original post with some of your config to see if I can spot a difference with mine?

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: I'd be interested to see your app.js, package.json and any other relevant bits where you prepare the Chart (e.g. to see if you manually load any adapters etc).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and couldn't find an answer. So I asked for some help on Github and we finally found a solution : https://github.com/symfony/ux/issues/1013

So on my project the issue was that it was installing two chart.js

```
npm why chart.js
```

And to fix it, I specified this on my package.json :

```
"chart.js": "^3.4.1 <3.9",
```

Then I deleted my package-lock.json and run :

```
npm install
```

Now you should be able to install date-fns and use 'type' => 'time' correctly with Symfony.
Have a look at the link, I detailed the whole manipulation for me.
I hope it will help you.