# How add adapters to symfony/ux-chartjs?

Tags: symfony, chart.js, symfonyux

Is there any possible options to use date adapters for time labels? I have exact same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653079/how-to-add-datetime-adapter-to-symfony-ux-chartjs), but it looks abandoned already.

In [Symfony UX Chart.js doc](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-chartjs/current/index.html#using-plugins) only about using plugins. But when I tried to import any date adapter in `assets/app.js` or custom controller, i only have error `This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.`